# Почему переадресовывает при отправке POST ajax запроса?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, есть проблема...не могу понять причину переадресации при отработке функции на кнопке createTest(). По идее rest запрос не должен перезагружать страницу. Подскажите, как убрать редирект при обработке? Заранее спасибо.

[HTML файл](https://github.com/LanguageRepository/rest-test/blob/master/src/main/resources/view/admin-panel/tests.html)

[JS файл](https://github.com/LanguageRepository/rest-test/blob/master/src/main/resources/static/js/test.js)

Answer (score 5):

Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow.

Преамбула.

Не очень вежливо, обращаясь за помощью, заставлять людей бродить в дебрях Вашего html и кода. Вынув из Вашей страницы небольшую часть, достаточную для воспроизведения проблемы и поместив эту часть в вопрос, Вы покажете, что приложили известные усилия, чтобы облегчить ответ тому, кто решит Вам помочь.

Ответ.

Первая строчка в `createTest(e)`

```
e.preventDefault();
```

но, вызывая эту функцию, Вы не передаете никакого параметра:

```
onclick="createTest()"
```

В первой строчке функции происходит ошибка, остальной код не выполняется, а идет дефолтное поведение элемента `button` внутри формы - очевидно, `submit`.

Если Вам не нужен `submit` по нажатию кнопки, ставьте ей `type="button"`.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте событие `submit` для того что бы отправлять данные на сервер

**Вот пример кода:**

```
$(".test-creation").submit(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault(); // отмена стандартного  поведения
  // можешь вызвать свою функцию createTest()

});
```

**Кнопку отправки нужно поправить на:**

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right" type="submit">Сохранить</button>
```

`onclick` уже не будет нужен в данном случае.